# Python: Summarising data frame and showing in countplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I have a data frame which looks like

```
   App_ID   Review_Rating   Grouping
0   1       5               High
2   4       3               Low
3   4       3               Low
4   16      5               High
6   16      5               High
13  13      2               Low
14  13      2               Low
17  16      4               High
19  20      2               Low
22  8       1               Low
23  8       1               Low
```

I want to summarize the data frame in following way

```
Grouping    High    Low
App_ID      
1   31.303116   68.696884
3   44.444444   55.555556
4   23.754153   76.245847
5   50.000000   50.000000
6   14.353612   85.646388
7   13.333333   86.666667
8   18.855932   81.144068
9   12.745098   87.254902
12  0.000000    100.000000
13  43.788820   56.211180
14  30.147059   69.852941
15  51.282051   48.717949
16  34.049931   65.950069
17  73.076923   26.923077
18  0.000000    100.000000
20  38.775510   61.224490
```

and show the summarised data frame by using countplot or barplot. I used the following code to summarise the data frame:

```
df_summay=pd.crosstab(df_cat_2.App_ID,df_cat_2.Grouping,df_cat_2.Review_Rating,aggfunc='sum',normalize='index')*100
```

The problem with summarise data frame is App_ID and Grouping columns dissolved by using above code. Hence I couldn't show summarise data frame in countplot/barplot. Is there any way or suggestion to avoid this issue? Thanks.

Comment: I honestly don't see how you go from that original dataframe to a "summary" that contains entirely different data. What exactly do the percentages represent? It's not so clear from the docs how you end up with those values

Comment: Sorry I show sample of first data frame and second data frame is complete summary @roganjosh

Comment: I think it's more a limitation on my understanding of crosstab tbh sorry

Comment: Is there any other way of doing the same thing!!!!!

Comment: I don't understand the need for all the exclamation marks. If I don't know what the numbers represent then it's not possible for me to suggest another approach

Comment: I already commented on you last question about using `melt` to get the frame into a shape that seaborn understands. Now reading this question, I'm not sure if I understood the complete aim. Maybe to start from a different perspective. What happens if you ignore seaborn for a moment and do `df_summary.plot.bar()`. Is this what you want? If not, can you explain what you want to have differently?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks, df_summary.plot.bar() works fine. This is want I want to plot.